# Pre-2005 CGI movie: set in space or sky, attack by mechanical bugs, the ending is a space funeral

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a movie/CGI animated film, years ago but sadly I do not remember the name.

All I remember is, that it is set in space/sky (can't say for sure which one, all I can remember is they were flying). There were some space pirates or something, and some weird bugs attacked them (machine bugs, like flying hornets but with guns).

And the most grappling memory I have of it is the last scene, where there is a space funeral, where they wrap this guy into some white cloth and let him fly in the space.
The story is blurry but I remember the beforementioned space pirates attacked some kind of ship, and it gave a steampunk-esque vibe to it all.

I watched it sometime around 2000-2006 not sure exactly.

The language was probably english, but honestly I have no idea whatsoever, I remember it being 3d though.

As for the language and west./japanese, I have no idea.

Comment: There is [guidance here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) which may help you remember any other details, which you can then [edit] to your question ;)

Comment: Was it a Western or a Japanese animation? Did you watch it in English?

Comment: I really don't know, i think it was Western though, but it's too distant to remember exactly.

Comment: [Sky Captain and the World of Tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_Captain_and_the_World_of_Tomorrow)?  Here's a [trailer](https://youtu.be/Ac7_v1DkSZw).

Comment: No this is not it, the one im looking for is an animated movie, there are no real actors. 100% animated.

Comment: @Jeznasliva Gotcha.  Sorry, I misinterpreted the CGI part.

Comment: Based on this list (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer-animated_films) there's none in that time period that match the description.

Comment: Are you sure it was CGI and not traditional animation?  The plot you describe is similar to the plot of [Les Maîtres du temps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Maîtres_du_temps)

Comment: Could it be [Battle for Terra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_for_Terra)? It's a bit out of your range of years (released in 2007), but fits your description of CGI sci-fi movie. In [this image](https://images4.myreviewer.co.uk/medium/0000223203.jpg) the aliens appear to look somewhat like flying hornets.

Comment: Maybe something from the Animatrix?

Answer (score 2):

Could the movie be [Titan AE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_A.E.)?

It's got pirates, and what you could consider bug-looking robots.

Comment: Can you please add some more explanation of why this matches the movie in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is *Aero-Troopers: The Nemeclous Crusade*.

I have the same vivid memory and this is the only film I've found that seems to tickle the memory, though I haven't re-watched it.

Comment: Can you please add some more explanation of why this matches the movie in the question?